# How to repeat text in JavaScript and append in between syntax?

Tags: javascript, dom, jasmine, mocha.js

I am stuck in somewhere in my code and need your help. Could be weird but important for me to achieve something in code.

I am writing a code snippet in my test cases under angular project. I need to pick an `bs-tooltip-container` element from HTML but they could be multiple.

So i need to add if loop conditions like

```
if(index === 0) {
    fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.nextElementSibling.children[1].innerText.trim()
}else if(index === 1) {
    fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.children[1].innerText.trim()

}else if(index === 2) {
    fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.children[1].innerText.trim()

}
```

If you noticed in above code then I am multiplying `.nextElementSibling` based on `index count`
[image: mutiple tooltip container]

They appended on the fly so we could not target them directly.

I am trying to use `FOR LOOP` so if I have multiple then I can repeat `.nextElementSibling`

I wrote some code like below

```
public static getToolTip(index = 0): DebugElement[] {
 for (let i = 0; i < index+1; i++) {
            tooltipNodes.push(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement`${nextElementSibling}.repeat(index)`.children[1].innerText.trim())
}
```

But this is not working for me. It makes mix of JS syntax with string. I do not know what should be write approach.

Basically I wanted to know **How can I repeat *.nextElementSibling* multiple times in code snippet?**

Comment: _"I need to pick an bs-tooltip-container element from HTML **but they could be multiple**."_ - Can you add a [mcve] or at least some markup (for e.g. the `index == 2` case). There might be better options than a loop...

Comment: @Andreas Added image in the description

Comment: Why not use `querySelectorAll` ?

Comment: @abhishekkhandait It was slightly tricky to use it in my case but it worked for me. Thanks for your time and solution. Keep Helping!

Comment: My concern solved here but I did not get answer of my actual question. Is there any way to achieve that I am expecting from my question?

Answer (score 0):

What you need could be something like

```
fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.parentNode.querySelector(`bs-tooltip-container:nth-of-type(${index})`);
```

or

```
fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('bs-tooltip-container')[index];
```

Comment: As I have mentioned in the description, We could not directly target them as they appended on the fly while test are running.

Comment: That's what MutationObervers are for